# How to properly inserting array to rxjs subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I get 3 times the same array, when i insert my array into a rxjs subject.

Parent component:

```
    const geoExistsArr: { lat: number, lng: number }[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < requiredKeys.length; j++) {
            // Some logic
        }
        if (has(x[i].data, 'lat') && has(x[i].data, 'lng')) {
            // Pushing to array
            const { lat, lng } = x[i].data;
            geoExistsArr.push({ lat, lng })
        }
    }
    console.log(geoExistsArr)
    // Adding the array to subj.
    this.locationSrv.setLocations(geoExistsArr)
```

Service:

```
setLocations(loc: ILocation) {
    this.geoArray = [...this.geoArray, loc]
    this.geoSubj$.next(this.geoArray)
}
```

Child-component (displaying values from subject):

```
    this.geoLocation$ = this.locationSrv.geoCoordinates$.pipe(
        switchMap((geo, idx) => {
            console.log(geo, idx) // <- problem here. this guy prints 3 times.
            geo.forEach(g => {
                console.log(g)
                requests.push(this.locationSrv.getAddressByLatLng$(g))
            });
            return concat(...requests).pipe(
                toArray()
            )
        }),
```

What should happen:
I store a single array to the subject.

I've gone blind to this bug, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am guessing that *geoLocation$* is a subscription. You need to unsubscribe the subscription in ngOnDestroy() method.

Whenever the componenet loads, it starts the subscription and it stays until you unsubscribe it. In your case, Multiple Subscriptions might have started. That's why you're getting repetion of values.

Just end the subscription on ngOnDestroy :)

Comment: where are you subscribing this.geoLocation$ ?

Comment: @HVSharma & @Fateme Fazli: It's unwrapped with async pipe in child html like so:
`<ng-container *ngIf="geoLocation$ | async as geo">`. It's the only place the observable is used, and the unsubscription should do any difference to the array size.

Comment: Please check how many times is setLocations called..

Comment: @AndrewAllen see the answer. The func wasn't called multiple times, but the observable was unwrapped arr.length num of times in the *ngFor loop in html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'll admit imma donkey. Inside my childcomponent i had a `*ngFor` loop running, and the template where i unwrap the `geolocations$ | async` was just inside that loop. @Andrew Allen suggested to look how many times the subjects' next() func was called, but for anyone reading this, check if your template observables are being unwrapped multiple times in the html somewhere. Thanks!